# Fixed point of a map $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Today I cam across the following exercise:

**exercise**

Let $\alpha: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a map with $\alpha^p=1$ for some prime $p$. Show that $\alpha$ has a fixed point.

**origin**

I found the exercise somewhere in my notes. The setting was roughly orientation and the orientation bundle.

**approach**

For my approach, of course I assumed that $\alpha$ has no fixed point and just as in the Brouwer fixed point theorem I obtained a map $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb S^{n-1}$. But now I don't know how to continue. I especially have trouble using the assumption that $\alpha^p=1$.

Any hint or help for this exercise is welcome!

Sincerely
Slin

**Edit**

This indeed is a duplicate of
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269486/can-a-finite-group-act-freely-as-homeomorphisms-on-mathbb-rn)

The answer uses some more advanced theory. I am interested how to do it the way it is suggested in Bredon's "Topology and Geometry". I cannot make the connection between $\mathbb R^n$ and coverings.

Comment: You are right, thank you.